# How to patch on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, apt

I have confronted Eclipse bug caused by  apt and JDT

also I have found bug report...

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387956

patch are attached on this thread, but not released.

so I want to build Own Eclipse with these patch.

how can i do?

Comment: Look at sources of nightly build eclipse at [eclipse build](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) starts with N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the [subproject](http://projects.eclipse.org/list-of-projects) this patch belongs to, check out the source, apply the patches, compile. Done.

Comment: thanks,but after build and copy jdt-core, Eclipse have errored.. No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor